# Paginacion de texto en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7

como podría hacer una paginación de un campo de mi BD. Se me complica ya que no es de registros, si no, de puro texto. Es decir, limitarme a 500 caracteres por página. Si son 1500 caracteres obviamente serian 3 Paginas.

Adjunto lo que tengo de Código PHP.

```
$result = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM moduloscurso WHERE idCurso='$p' and idModulo='$idModulo'    ");  
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $nM = $row['nombreModulo'];/*Obteniendo el nombre del curso seleccionado*/
    $tit = $row['tituloModulo'];/*Obteniendo el titulo del curso seleccionado*/
    $contenido   = $row['contenido'];/*Obteniendo la descripcion del curso seleccionado*/

    $a = strlen($contenido);/*Se obtiene el numero de caracteres*/
    echo $a;
}

$regXpagina = 500;/*Numero de caracteres por pagina*/
//echo "registros: ".$registros;
$paginas = $a/$regXpagina;
$paginas = ceil($paginas);/*redondeando para que aparezcan todos los registros*/
//echo $paginas;

/*mostrar los Cursos al usuario*/ 
$iniciar = ($_GET['pagina']-1)*$regXpagina;



$resultt= $bd->query("SELECT contenido FROM moduloscurso WHERE idCurso='$p' and idModulo='$idModulo'
                     LIMIT $iniciar,$regXpagina");  
while ($row1= mysqli_fetch_array($resultt)) {

    echo '

    <p style="text-align: justify;">'.$row1['contenido'].'</p>

    ';

}
```

Me aparece todo el texto obtenido y no los 500 caracteres por pagina.

Answer (score 0):

No he visto nada que pueda servir para paginar un campo desde SQL pero si se puede hacer lo que necesitas usando el codigo PHP.

Con estas dos variables puedes establecer el bloque y hacer la paginacion:

```
$bloquesChars = 20; // bloque
$paginaActual = 2; // variables de paginacion
```

La variable **row['texto']** es la que recibe el contenido del campo.

Aqui te adjunto un ejemplo que puede ayudarte:

```
<?php

   $row['texto']="The main benefit to using templates is the clear separation 
   they create between the presentation logic and the rest of your application. 
   Templates have the sole responsibility of displaying formatted content. 
   They are not responsible for data lookup, persistence or other more complex tasks. 
   This leads to cleaner, more readable code which is especially helpful in a 
   team environment where developers work on the server-side code (controllers, models) 
   and designers work on the client-side code (markup)";

    // calculando, cantidad de paginas por chars;
    $longitud = strlen ($row['texto']);
    $bloquesChars = 20;
    $paginaActual = 2; // variables de paginacion
    $paginas = ceil($longitud /$bloquesChars); // total de paginas

    // declarar var
    $CharInicio=0;
    $CharFin=0;
    $cadena='';

    // haciendo el bloque de paginas
    if($paginas >= $paginaActual && $paginaActual>0) {
        $CharInicio = ($paginaActual==1)? 0 : ($bloquesChars * ($paginaActual-1));
        $CharFin = $bloquesChars * $paginaActual;
        $cadena = substr ( $row['texto'] , $CharInicio , $$bloquesChars );
    }

    // salida 
    echo "<br> Logitud Chars: " . $longitud;
    echo "<br> paginas: " . $paginas; 
    echo "<br> bloque: " . $bloquesChars; 
    echo "<br> paginas Actual: " . $paginaActual; 
    echo "<br> char inicio: " . $CharInicio;
    echo "<br> char Fin: " . $CharFin;
    echo "<br> Mostrar texto:";
    echo  "<p>". utf8_encode($cadena) . "</p>"; 
    echo '<br><br>' . utf8_encode($row['texto'])

?>
```

La Salida es como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]